# how do I solve this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an autoencoder and I try to use the specific value of input layer in in intermediate layer using lambda and produce a new tensor and send to next layers but it produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 99, in 
>       model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 93, in **init**
>       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 231, in _init_graph_network
>       self.inputs, self.outputs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1366, in _map_graph_network
>       tensor_index=tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1353, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1325, in build_map
>       node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

this is my code and after adding the first lambda layer it produces this error! could you please tell why this error has happened? I appreciate your help? the thing I need is sth like this:
`wtm={[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]}` I choose `wtm[:,i,j]` and produce new tensor with shape `(28,28,1)` and with value  wtm[:,i,j].

```
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
w_expand=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_expand=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
#w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
#wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
#wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
#wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
w_test=w_test.reshape((1,4,4,1))

wtm=Input((4,4,1))
        image = Input((28, 28, 1))
        conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
        conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
        conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
        BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
        encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)

   rep=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.repeat(x,28))
    a=rep(Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm))

    add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
    encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,a])


    #-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_merged)
    deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
    deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
    deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
    BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)
    #DrO2=Dropout(0.25,name='DrO2')(BNd)

    decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 
    #model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)

    model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

    decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

    #----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
    convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
    convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='convl2w')(convw1)#20
    #Avw1=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw2)
    convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
    convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
    #Avw2=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw4)
    convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl5w')(convw4)#8
    convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
    convw7 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl7w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)#4
    convw8 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conl8w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw7)#4
    convw9 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl9w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw8)#4
    convw10 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl10w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw9)#4
    BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw10)
    pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNed)  

    w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

    w_extraction.summary()
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
opt=SGD(momentum=0.99)
w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'decoder_output': 0.2, 'reconstructed_W': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=40)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_5x5F_dp_gn.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=w_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=1,
          batch_size=64, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='E:concatnatenetwork', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
```

when I implement it, this error is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,a])
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py",
>   line 687, in call
>       return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmf55.png))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 866, in binary_op_wrapper
>       return func(x, y, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 301, in add
>       "Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 488, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3274, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1792, in **init**
>       control_input_ops)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1631, in _create_c_op
>       raise ValueError(str(e))
>
> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 28 and 4 for
>   'lambda_9/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,28,28,1], [4,28,1].

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keras every layer should be an instance of keras's Layer class. On the following line

```py
a=rep(wtm[1,1])
```

You are selecting tensor element without using keras layer. This line is causing the error. You should change the line to the following to deal with the error.

```py
a=rep(Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm))
```

### Edit 1.

Since wtm has shape of [None, 4,4,1](you can try to print the shape), `wtm[1,1]` will select one element from first dimension and then the first element from selected element. If you want to get [1,1] shape array what you could do is index the first three dimensions. Here you should mind the batch size too, so what you want is to have array with shape [Batchsize, 1]. This could be done as follows.

```py
new_wtm = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[:,1,1,:])(wtm)
```

Now new_wtm.shape would be [None, 1] and calling repeat method will produce array with shape[None, rep, 1].

```py
rep=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.repeat(x,28))
a=rep(Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[:,1,1,:])(wtm))
print(a.shape) # [None, 28, 1]
```

I hope this will resolve the issue

## Edit 2:

To get `a` with shape [None, 28, 28,1], you need to use tile method.

```py
rep=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.tile(x,[1, 28, 28, 1]))
a_1 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 1, 1, :])(wtm)

a=rep(Kr.layers.Reshape([1,1,1])(a_1))
```

**The test code**

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Activation,GaussianNoise,Dropout,BatchNormalization,MaxPool2D,AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AtrousConv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;
#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------

#wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
w_expand=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_expand=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
#w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
#wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
#wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
#wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
w_test=w_test.reshape((1,4,4,1))

#wt_expand=wt_expand.reshape((1,28,28,1))

#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
#conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e', kernel_initializer='Orthogonal',bias_initializer='glorot_uniform')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
#DrO1=Dropout(0.25,name='Dro1')(BN)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)

#-----------------------adding w---------------------------------------


#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rep0=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.tile(x,[1, 28, 28, 1]),name='aux0')
a_0 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0, 0, :])(wtm)

a0=rep0(Kr.layers.Reshape([1,1,1])(a_0))

rep1=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.tile(x,[1, 28, 28, 1]),name='aux1')
a_1 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0, 1, :])(wtm)

a1=rep1(Kr.layers.Reshape([1,1,1])(a_1))

rep2=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.tile(x,[1, 28, 28, 1]),name='aux2')
a_2 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0, 2, :])(wtm)

a2=rep2(Kr.layers.Reshape([1,1,1])(a_2))

rep3=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.tile(x,[1, 28, 28, 1]),name='aux3')
a_3 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0, 3, :])(wtm)

a3=rep3(Kr.layers.Reshape([1,1,1])(a_3))


add_const1 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4],name='decoder_output')
encoded_merged = add_const1([encoded,a0,a1,a2,a3])

w=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=encoded_merged)

w.summary()
#----------------------training the model--------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------Data preparesion----------------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
opt=SGD(lr=0.0001,momentum=0.9)
w.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse'}, metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=40)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('los4x4_repw.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=w.fit([x_train,w_expand], x_train,
          epochs=1,
          batch_size=32, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], x_validation))
w.summary()

layer_name = 'lambda_96'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=watermark_extraction.input,outputs=watermark_extraction.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict([x_test[8000:8001],w_test])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

rows = 8
columns = 8

first = intermediate_output

for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
    img = intermediate_output[0,:,:,i-1]
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest',cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I updated my code and this produces this error. please help me what should I do?

Comment: the first error had solved, but It produces new error I put above. in this line (rep=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.repeat(x,28)) , I wanted to repeat wtm(1,1) along each axis and produce a (28,28) output but the output of this is (4,28)! what should I do to repeat one value along two axis 28 times or maybe it is better to say fill a tensor with shape (28,28) with wtm(1,1)? could you please help me with this? I really need your guidance

Comment: what is the output shape of Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm)? I think it should be (1,1) but it is (4,1)?! why? could you please help me how to solve this and access to only one element of wtm?

Comment: Thank you. based on your output the output shape will be [None,28,1]. but I need to produce a tensor with shape [None,28,28]. how can I do this? I think my code just repeat wtm[:,1,1,:] in one dimension but I need a code to repeat it in two dimensions. could you please help me with this?

Comment: shape [None,28,28]..., are you sure? You cannot add this array with `encoded` because encoded has shape of [None, 28, 28, 1]. So what you are looking is to get tensor with shape [None, 28, 28, 1]. I'll update the code to reflect that.

Comment: yes, I mean [None,28,28,1], sorry for my bad explanation. but I could not find your updated code.

Comment: @david I've posted now

Comment: Edit one should work with broadcasting. Is there any reason you didn't chose that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190513/discussion-between-david-and-mitiku).

Comment: I used your code but it produces this error: 

assert ndim(x) == 2 
AssertionError

Comment: could you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: did you see the error? I do not know why this error has happened.

Comment: Thank you it seems work but when I saw the different values of wtm which are 0 and 1 but by changing the index in a_1 = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 1, 1, :])(wtm)
the a_1 value is 0 all the time and I do not know this is my fault or the code has a problem. for checking it I test the network in one epoch and see the output of each layer and I saw a is zero all the time:((( could you please what should I do? is this my fault? I am really confused.

Comment: I check my code with this activations = keract.get_activations(watermark_extraction, [x_test[7500:7501],w_test]), but it is weird that although all w_test's value is 1 but it feed a zero tensor into the network. if you are sure your code can extract each value correctly based on its index, I try to find out the problem?!

Comment: the first dimension is the batch size and the second and third are indexes of wtm and the fourth dimension is the number of channels that here because we have grayscale images it is 1. now, I need each value of wtm in index i,j and your code do this, right?

Comment: I asked it because when I test it I receive 0 all the time and I want to know it is my fault or maybe I could not say you what do I need?? could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: I test with different wtm and I am sure it gives me 0 all the time, but I do not know why? could you please tell me what is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: sorry, Mitiku did you see my question? could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: could you elaborate on how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry, it means I should ask the question in new question again?

Comment: I think so. The question does not explain the issue your are facing now. Please try to  specify the steps required to reproduce the error.

Comment: I asked the question in new link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403317/accessing-to-each-tensor-values-but-producing-same-output-for-different-values and I hope you can solve my problem:)

Comment: dear Mitiku, when I implement your code it produces true output ( tensors with all value 0 or all value 1 with size 28x28) but when I use plt.imshow to see the output of layer it shows a black output although it should be white and its value also is correct but in the output it shows different. do you know why does it happen? if this error is just in showing no problem but I want to know it send true value to next layer

Comment: I put the output above.

Comment: in the above picture, the right image should be white and its value is 1 but it shows a black image!