# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train my model using Keras and TensorFlow for Big5 personality traits.

**I have included the code snippets below. Full code can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nxjfPUWFWDW9jtoVK7AzKWuTT-C2o-Cb?usp=sharing)**

Code

```
#### Train data preparation
N = datasets[0].shape[0]
conv_input_width = W.shape[1]
conv_input_height = int(datasets[0].shape[1]-1)

# For each word write a word index (not vector) to X tensor
train_X = np.zeros((N, conv_input_height), dtype=np.int)
train_Y = np.zeros((N, 2), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(conv_input_height):
        train_X[i, j] = datasets[0][i, j]
    
print ('train_X.shape = {}'.format(train_X.shape))
print ('train_Y.shape = {}'.format(train_Y.shape))

#### Validation data preparation
Nv = datasets[1].shape[0]

# For each word write a word index (not vector) to X tensor
val_X = np.zeros((Nv, conv_input_height), dtype=np.int)
val_Y = np.zeros((Nv, 2), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(Nv):
    for j in range(conv_input_height):
        val_X[i, j] = datasets[1][i, j]
print('val_X.shape = {}'.format(val_X.shape))
print('val_Y.shape = {}'.format(val_Y.shape))
for i in range(Nv):
    val_Y[i,data_train.iloc[i,3]] = 1


from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras import backend
backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')


# Number of feature maps (outputs of convolutional layer)
N_fm = 200
# kernel size of convolutional layer
kernel_size = 5

model = Sequential()
# Embedding layer (lookup table of trainable word vectors)
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=W.shape[0], 
                    output_dim=W.shape[1], 
                    input_length=conv_input_height,
                    weights=[W], 
                    embeddings_constraint=unitnorm(),
                    name = 'e_l'))
# Reshape word vectors from Embedding to tensor format suitable for Convolutional layer
model.add(Reshape((1, conv_input_height, conv_input_width)))

# first convolutional layer
model.add(Convolution2D(N_fm,
                        kernel_size, 
                        conv_input_width,
                        kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                        padding='valid',
                        kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
# ReLU activation
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# aggregate data in every feature map to scalar using MAX operation
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2725,1), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(128,kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Inner Product layer (as in regular neural network, but without non-linear activation function)
model.add(Dense(2))
# SoftMax activation; actually, Dense+SoftMax works as Multinomial Logistic Regression
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Custom optimizers could be used, though right now standard adadelta is employed
opt = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**I am facing an error in this line**

```
model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(val_X,val_Y), callbacks=[tb])
```

**Error is**

```
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-32-d7050a2e4247> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(val_X,val_Y), callbacks=[tb])

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    853       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    854       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 855       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    856     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    857       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Please Note**: I tried tweaking my code, especially the validation and training data but it doesn't work. I referred to Keras'API for the .fit() method and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63850359/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-in-google-colab) to resolve my error but it hasn't worked either.

Just to mention, I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273067/how-do-i-solve-this-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute) as well but couldn't solve my error.

**UPDATE**

conv_input_height= 2729

kernel_size = 5

conv_input_height-kerel_size + 1 = 2725

**After changing values, the code is**

```
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2725,1), padding='same'))
```

**UPDATED ERROR**

```
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-62-04e7e3b528b5> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for i in range(N_epoch):
----> 4     model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size=32,epochs=10, verbose=1)
      5     output = model.predict_proba(val_X, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
      6     # find validation accuracy using the best threshold value t

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

RuntimeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:498 minimize
        return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:635 apply_gradients
        "name": name,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2941 merge_call
        return self._merge_call(merge_fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2948 _merge_call
        return merge_fn(self._strategy, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:683 _distributed_apply  **
        var, apply_grad_to_update_var, args=(grad,), group=False))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2494 update
        return self._update(var, fn, args, kwargs, group)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3431 _update
        return self._update_non_slot(var, fn, (var,) + tuple(args), kwargs, group)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3437 _update_non_slot
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:650 apply_grad_to_update_var  **
        "Cannot use a constraint function on a sparse variable.")

    RuntimeError: Cannot use a constraint function on a sparse variable.
```

I have also checked the snippets for syntactical errors but there are none. Please can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you forgot to set the value for `conv_input_height-kernel_size` in the `MaxPooling2D` layer.

Comment: @yudhiesh, after adding the values I got this error (see the updated question above)

Comment: The import for UnitNorm should either be `tf.keras.constraints.unit_norm` or `tf.keras.constraints.UnitNorm` try changing that

Comment: Seems to be an error with Keras as well but [this is the only answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33755#issuecomment-708061069) I found that works for it